# How do i configure rails to point to my openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

Am completely new to ruby, I'm having issues with openssl. Rails keeps throwing errors that it cannot load openssl.

Whereas:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "openssl"
==> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

But each time i type rails i get the following

```
root@subomi:~/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit# rails
The most common rails commands are:
 generate     Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console      Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server       Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 test         Run tests except system tests (short-cut alias: "t")
 test:system  Run system tests
 dbconsole    Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
              (short-cut alias: "db")

 new          Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
              new application called MyApp in "./my_app"


All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
In addition to those commands, there are:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails.rb:12:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/subomi/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/subomi/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:31:in `rake_tasks'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:40:in `formatted_rake_tasks'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:10:in `printing_commands'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:91:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:91:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:91:in `block in sorted_groups'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:26:in `block in transform_values!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:25:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb:25:in `transform_values!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:91:in `sorted_groups'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:84:in `print_commands'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/help/help_command.rb:9:in `help'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/subomi/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/subomi/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/subomi/Documents/ruby/learning/railsapp/readit/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

When I also type in

```
$ which openssl
$ /usr/bin/openssl
```

My question is how then do I point rails in particular or this even the wrong question to ask .. Am not sure thanks.

Comment: which ruby version you are using

Comment: ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: run this command in your terminal ruby -ropenssl -e "puts :OK"

Comment: try running this commands
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall all --force

Comment: No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
rvm: command not found

Comment: thats means rvm is not properly install

Comment: how do i install rvm properly?

Answer (score 0):

install ruby using rvm

- gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
- source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
- rvm install 2.3.4

you can follow this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm